# SQL Server CE throws error Parameter is not valid when using COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, coalesce

It seems that SQL Server CE does not like `COALESCE` with my column.

If my query has `COALESCE(ep.value, '') as id`, the query fails with

> Parameter is not valid

I've tried using (`case ep.value when null then '' else ep.value end`) but then I get other errors about `NTEXT` etc.

Does anyone know of another way to convert nulls to something non-nullish?

UPDATE:

The full query is rather complex and would take a long time to explain, but here it is for the curious.

```
    SELECT COALESCE(ep.value, '') as domainId , [p].[id], [p].[firstName], [p].[middleName], [p].[lastName], [p].[isDeleted], ...    
FROM Patient p 

INNER JOIN PatientOrganisation po on p.id = po.patientFk  

left join extendedproperty ep on ep.entityId = p.id 

left join (select sgu.id, sgu.unitFk 
           from StaffGroupUnit sgu 
           where sgu.staffGroupFk = '3d364f5b-b5ff-456a-bf33-d8b48bf195b2' and sgu.isDeleted = 0) as bat on bat.unitFk = po.unitFk 

where p.isDeleted = 0 and po.isDeleted = 0  AND 
      COALESCE(ep.metadatafk,'55b009d5-cead-4b62-ad04-526b57a02ed2')='55b009d5-cead-4b62-ad04-526b57a02ed2' and 
      COALESCE(ep.isdeleted,0)=0  AND 
      (not exists(select 1 from staffgroupunit sgu where sgu.staffGroupFk = '3d364f5b-b5ff-456a-bf33-d8b48bf195b2' and sgu.isDeleted=0) OR bat.id IS NOT NULL)  
order by p.lastName, p.firstName
```

Now yes, I know this query is horrendous and I have actually fixed the problem by removing some parts of it.  The really interesting thing is that this query would mostly work.  When it failed with 'parameter is not valid' I could run the exact same query using Visual Studio or Management Studio and it would work just fine.

We are using CE 3.5 becuase one of our products is Windows Mobile.  I suspect this is just a bug in CE that an upgrade will fix.

Cheers

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your whole select statement?

Comment: What version of CE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`CASE var WHEN NULL THEN …` is not a good practice.

Use this:

```
CASE WHEN ep.value IS NULL THEN NEWID() ELSE ep.value END
```

or just this:

```
COALESCE(ep.value, NEWID())
```

Comment: Actually, WHEN NULL is the correct format, IS NULL fails.  At least in CE.